# Need help on updating activity_date in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a table as example mentioned below. I need to update the date of `activity_type 3721` as the activity date of `3770/3771` for all the individual_ID which contains `activity_type 3721` and either `activity_type 3770 or 3771`

```
[IND_ID]   [ACTIVITY_TYPE]   [ACTIVITY_DATE]
   100           3770           12/12/2014
   100           3721              Null
   103           3771          21/06/2017
   103           3721              Null
   122           3770          07/07/2017
   122           3721              Null
```

Here is my below query which is not working

```
declare 
@actiondate DATETIME,
@ind_ref int

SET @actiondate = (select ACTION_DATE  from ACTIVITY_LOG where activity_type in (3770,3771) and INDIVIDUAL_REF=@ind_ref) 

UPDATE ACTIVITY_LOG 
SET ACTION_DATE= (
      CASE 
      WHEN ACTIVITY_TYPE='3721' AND ACTION_DATE IS NULL AND ACTIVITY_LOG.INDIVIDUAL_REF=@ind_ref 
      THEN @actiondate
      ELSE ACTION_DATE
      END) 
FROM ACTIVITY_LOG
```

Comment: What have you tried, and why didn't it work? What dbms are you using?

Comment: which database system? What did you try? You can select the other values into variables and then use them in your updates.

Comment: sql server , im trying to update activity_date of activity_type 3721 as the activity_date of activity_type 3770

Comment: Each IND_ID will either contain activity_type 3770 or 3771 .@ADyson

Comment: Sorry I misread the data. Removed my comment.

Comment: I'm actually curious about that query you tried. Could you add it to the question?

Comment: @LukStorms I have added my query.. I was suppose to pass ind_ref and loop through the record to make the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update with a self join is one way.

Another way is to set the column to a top 1 sub-query that  self-joins the table.

For example:

```
UPDATE t 
SET [ACTIVITY_DATE] = (
     SELECT TOP 1 t2.[ACTIVITY_DATE] 
     FROM YourTable t2
     WHERE t2.[ACTIVITY_TYPE] IN (3770, 3771)
       AND t2.[ACTIVITY_DATE] IS NOT NULL
       AND t2.[IND_ID] = t.[IND_ID]
     ORDER BY t2.[ACTIVITY_DATE] DESC
    )
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.[ACTIVITY_TYPE] = 3721
  AND t.[ACTIVITY_DATE] IS NULL;
```

That ORDER BY is there just incase there's more than one 3770 and/or 3771 for the same IND_ID.

Using a self-join it would something like this:

```
UPDATE t
SET [ACTIVITY_DATE] = t2.[ACTIVITY_DATE]
FROM YourTable t
JOIN YourTable t2
  ON ( t2.[IND_ID] = t.[IND_ID]
   AND t2.[ACTIVITY_TYPE] IN (3770, 3771)
   AND t2.[ACTIVITY_DATE] IS NOT NULL
  )
WHERE t.[ACTIVITY_TYPE] = 3721
  AND t.[ACTIVITY_DATE] IS NULL;
```

Which should be faster, but then you can't use the ORDER BY.

Comment: I run the query its saying 0 rows affected @lukstorms

Comment: @Biswa It worked for me when I tested it with a table variable.  Did you perhaps already update your table with JohnHC's query? Because then this one wouldn't update anything extra. Notice the criteria `t.[ACTIVITY_DATE] IS NULL`. Plus I assumed that ACTIVITY_TYPE is an INT. Is it perhaps a VARCHAR?

Comment: Hi Lukstorms, sorry about that. I have just run it once again with action date instead of activity date as i wrongly spelled the column name. Its running now taking much longer

Comment: Awesome Lukstorms, it work like charm. thanks you brother.

Answer (score 3):

Use UPDATE (obviously) with a self JOIN:

```
update x1
set x1.ACTIVITY_DATE = x2.ACTIVITY_DATE

from MyTable x1
inner join MyTable x2
  on x1.IND_ID =x2.IND_ID
  and x1.ACTIVITY_TYPE <> x2.ACTIVITY_TYPE
where x1.ACTIVITY_DATE is null
and x2.ACTIVITY_DATE is not null
```

Comment: Whats that x2 is ? i one table only

Comment: @Biswa it's a self-join. You're joining the "one table" to itself.

Comment: x2 is an alias, as is x1, they are both aliases for MyTable. This is alluded to when I said SELF JOIN, as in the table joins to itself.